# Jira 7 project CSV import without knowing the project type attribute name

Tags: filter, jira, jql, csv-import, project-types

With version 7 of Jira, all projects are now classified in 3 different project types:

- `Software projects`
- `Business projects`
- `Service Desk projects`

I wonder if there is a way to filter all issues within `Software projects`, and if so, which would be the JQL query to use.

I normally import issues from a CSV file where I specify the project name, but since this change I am not able to do it, as Jira is expecting me to specify the project type on the import configuration file, but I don't know which name to use.

Answer (score 0):

Projects are defined above the scope of the query engine:

> All users on the JIRA instance will be able to see all projects, but what features they see and what actions they can take are determined by their application access and the project specific permissions.

Projects can be converted on a case-by-case basis:

> At some point you may wish to convert an existing project to a different project type.  For instance, you can convert a JIRA Software  project to a JIRA Core  project at the end of a JIRA Software  evaluation period, or when your team grows. You can only convert to project types of JIRA applications that you have installed. Note that a project administrator may also change the project type.

```
    Choose > Projects, and select the relevant project..
    Select Details in the Project settings menu.
    Change the project type, and click Save details. Only project types for applications you have installed will be available.
```

> Jira is expecting me to specify the project type on the import configuration file, but I don't know which name to use.

- Business type is for non-software projects, and does not include Agile boards
- Software type is for software projects, and includes Agile boards

The minimum information for a CSV import is:

```
IssueType, Summary, Project Name, Project Key
bug, "First issue", Sample, SAMP
bug, "Second issue", Sample, SAMP
task, "Third issue", Example, EXAM
```

The project key is the prefix for all issue IDs in your JIRA project.

To avoid project type in a JQL query, use one of the following:

- Find issues in projects that are led by a specific user:

  ```
  projectsLeadByUser(username)
  ```
- Find issues in components that are led by a specific user:

  ```
  componentsLeadByUser(username)
  ```
- Perform searches based on issues that are linked to a specified issue:

  ```
  linkedIssues(issueID)
  ```

**References**

- [JIRA User's Guide, Searching for Issues: Advanced searching - functions reference](https://confluence.atlassian.com/jirasoftwarecloud/advanced-searching-functions-reference-764478342.html])
- [Importing data from CSV: Importing issues into multiple JIRA projects](https://confluence.atlassian.com/adminjiraserver071/importing-data-from-csv-802592885.html#ImportingdatafromCSV-ImportingissuesintomultipleJIRAprojects)
- [JIRA Applications and Project Types Overview](https://confluence.atlassian.com/adminjiraserver072/jira-applications-and-project-types-overview-828787539.html)
- [JIRA Server: Defining a Project](https://confluence.atlassian.com/adminjiraserver072/defining-a-project-828787707.html)
- [JIRA Command Line Interface Guide: Examples](https://bobswift.atlassian.net/wiki/display/JCLI/Examples)
- [JIRA Configuration Manager Support Matrix](https://botronsoft.atlassian.net/wiki/display/CMJ/Configuration+Object+Support+Matrix#)

Comment: I'm not able to import issues if I dont specify the project type. I get the following error message:<pre>  `For the CSV import to be successful, you must specify a CSV header row that corresponds to the Project type. Available project types are: software, business.` <\pre>Nevertheless, I was able to workaround this by adding the following to the configuration file I use for import <pre>`"Project type" : {
        "jira.field" : "project.type"
      },`<\pre>